# VBA Import/Copy Specifc Worksheet witout Opening Workbook

Tags: vba, excel, import, macros

thanks in advance.

I've spent nearly two days routing around but can't quite find/workout what I need.

I need to get an entire specific worksheet from a closed workbook **without** opening (even in the background).

Further info:

1) My source file has several sheets that I don't want/need. I only need one and it seems sloppy to copy all and trim the data down (plus it means moving large amounts of data unnecessarily).

2) The end goal of this is to save the sheet as a third, seperate, workbook. So if you know a way that helps this that doubles your awesomeness.

3)Targeting individual cells is not a viable solution, there's too much and the code would be huge/akward/cumbersome.

4) I've found a way to import *all* sheets into my operating/active workbook but cant figure out how to make it target a specific sheet (I'm missing osmehting simple I'm sure).
 Test code snippet:

```
Dim Importsheet As Worksheet 
Sheets.Add Type:= _
"C:\Users\haa\Documents\Personal\My Hours E2V-mk3.xlsm\"
```

Seems simple enough right?

5) Finally, I've seen some potential solution routes that uses "executeexcel4macro" (something I've never even seen before) but so far it only seems to target cell ranges not sheets.

That's all the key info. I really have dug around (and would have liked to crack this myself). Reminder that I'm looking for a way to do this without copying individual cells or opening the source sheet.

Thanks again campers!

Comment: I think you'll need to use a data connection. The following website seems to have a potential solution: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=27288

Answer (score 0):

*4) I've found a way to import all sheets into my operating/active workbook but cant figure out how to make it target a specific sheet (I'm missing osmehting simple I'm sure). Test code snippet*

Import all the sheets, then delete all but the one you want to keep.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as I said in my question that is not a good approach for my needs. I need a way of doing this without copying all sheets and deleting the bits I don't need.